# How to set O_NONBLOCKING flag in Unix

Tags: c, unix, ipc, nonblocking, flags

I am writing a sender/reader IPC C program for class, and I am having trouble setting the O_NONBLOCK flag to 0 so that my reader will block when the buffer it is attempting to read from is empty. Here are the functions I am using:

```
int set_nonblock_flag(int desc, int value)
{
        int oldflags = fcntl(desc, F_GETFL, 0);
        if (oldflags == -1)
                return -1;
        if (value != 0)
                oldflags |= O_NONBLOCK;
        else
                oldflags &= ~O_NONBLOCK;
        return fcntl(desc, F_SETFL, oldflags);
}
```

**main()**

```
main ()
{
        int fd[2], nbytes;
        char readbuff[26];
        int r_pid = 0;
        int s_pid = 0;

        /* THIS IS ALL UPDATED!*/
        fd[0] = open("fd.txt",O_RDONLY);
        fd[1] = open("fd.txt",O_WRONLY);
        set_nonblock_flag(fd[0], 0);
        set_nonblock_flag(fd[1], 0);
        /* END UPDATES */

        pipe(fd);

        r_pid = fork();
        if (r_pid < 0) /* error */
        {
                fprintf( stderr, "Failed to fork receiver\n" );
                exit( -1 );
        }
        else if (r_pid == 0) /* this is the receiver */
        {
                fprintf( stdout, "I, %d am the receiver!\n", getpid() );

                close( fd[1] ); /* close write end */
                nbytes = read( fd[0], readbuff, 1 );
                printf ("nonblocking flag = %d\n", fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0));
                printf ("Nbytes read: %d\n", nbytes );
        }

... /* rest of function removed */
```

The line `printf ("nonblocking flag = %d\n", fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0));`
 is just returning -1 as the flag status. Shouldn't it be 0 if it is cleared?

Answer (score 2):

You are calling set_nonblock_flag with first argument as an array of ints.
Here's a snippet from fcntl manpage. The first argument should be a file descriptor.

> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>    #include <fcntl.h>
>
>    int fcntl(int fildes, int cmd, ...);
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> The  fcntl()  function  shall perform the operations described below on open files. The fildes argument is a file
>          descriptor.

I think you want to first call pipe and then call set_nonblock_flag. So, I think what you really want is the following:

```
int fd[2];
...
pipe(fd);
set_nonblock_flag(fd[0], 0);
```

Comment: Thank you! That does solve my warnings, but now the flag is set to 2. Do you know what may be causing the issue?

Comment: I think your if condition is wrong. Instead of  `if (value != 0)` you want `if (value == 0)`.

Comment: It's still coming up as 2

Comment: @Zach: If you get -1 returned from `fcntl()`, you should look at `errno` (possibly via `strerror()`) to see what the problem is.  It could be EBADF (bad file descriptor), for example.  The value you passed is then not a valid open file descriptor.  In the code fragment you show, you've not initialized the file descriptors, so you've got two indeterminate numbers as file descriptors.  The error returns suggest that you're lucky enough not to have a valid file descriptor in them — so the code fails.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for that, just printed out what the return was and it was -1. I'm really new to C so I'm confused at how to send a proper file descriptor. If you look at my updated main code I set fd[0] and fd[1] to be the same .txt file with different permission flags, but I still get -1. Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should check the value in `fd[0]` before you open the file a second time.  You should then check the value in `fd[1]`.  At a guess, both of them are -1, indicating that the file you're trying to open doesn't exist.  Since you've not specified `O_CREAT`, the file won't be created (just as well really; that requires a third argument for the file mode).  Always check system calls, especially ones that open a file or something similar, and ones which read from a file.